# how to encrypt and decrypt data stored in sessionStorage or localStorage in angular

Tags: angular, encryption, local-storage, cryptojs, session-storage

I am using SessionStorageService of ngx-webstorage to store data in sessionStorage.
But it is visible to user under **Application > Session storage**. Data stored should be encrypted and decrypted.
Any suggestion for same

options may be

secure-web-storage which use cryptoJS, but facing issue while storing object in session.

Comment: What is your question? You may ask how to solve your cryptoJS problem rather than asking what anyone would suggest (this might also totally depend on the way you're going to use it, but nothing it said about your use case/application). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi guys, I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-web-storage which stores key as well as value in encrypted format.